# Format function in c#

Tags: c#

I have a format string **formatStr** and DateTime string **Dt**.I need to replace patterns in formatStr with corresponding values from Dt.

Here is template of the function -

```
string stringFormat(formatStr, Dt)

%Year has to replace with year
%Month has to replace with month
.
.
.
and so on
```

Note: formatStr is constant and  Dt is of Datetime type

For example

```
stringFormat(@"D:\my\POC\%Year\%Month\%Day\File_%Year_%Month_%Day_%Hour_%Minute_%Second_%Milisecond.ss", "2015-03-29 23:55:01.293")
```

should return - "D:\my\POC\2015\03\29\File_2015_03_29_23_55_01_293.ss"

I am okay with changing FormatStr.

Comment: If it already returns that value, what is wrong with it? You should show the method `stringFormat`. `"2015-03-29 23:55:01.293"` is also a `string` not a `DateTime`.

Comment: `String.Format()` (aptly named) is probably what you want rather than your own method - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: To use String.Format() i need to pass Dt parameters so many times to seperate all attributes. Is there any inbuilt method which can be directly used?

Comment: What is the question here? Is that last part what you want or what you already have?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have Dt(2015-03-29 23:55:01.293) and i want to get "D:\my\POC\2015\03\29\File_2015_03_29_23_55_01_293.ss".

Comment: Still unclear/incomplete. Is `"2015-03-29 23:55:01.293"` coming in as a string or as a DateTime?

Comment: Dt is coming as string. I modified Artiom's answer. Added Convert.ToDateTime() and i am able to achieve this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change format to:

```
String.Format(@"D:\my\POC\{0:yyyy}\{0:MM}\{0:dd}\File_{0:yyyy}_{0:MM}_{0:dd}_{0:hh}_{0:mm}_{0:ss}_{0:fff}.ss", DateTime.Now)
```

or you can use string Replace function for each parameter. Or even with regex. But I would go with 1st solution

Comment: I modified it a bit String.Format(@"D:\my\POC\{0:yyyy}\{0:MM}\{0:dd}\File_{0:yyyy}_{0:MM}_{0:dd}_{0:hh}_{0:mm}_{0:ss}_{0:fff}.ss", Convert.ToDateTime(Dt)) because Dt is coming as string. Thanks